# viewer js only shows index.html

Tags: javascript, html, apache, iframe

I'm trying to display .pdfs in an iframe on my website, but following the instructions on viewerjs.org yields an iframe that only shows the index.html file in ViewerJS. My apache document root is at
    `/var/www/lifecycle/htdocs`
the ViewerJS directory is at 
    `/var/www/lifecycle/htdocs/js/ViewerJS`
the pdf I'm trying to display is at the apache document root. I have up-to-date php, apache2, and iced-tea plugin for the test browser. The relevant iframe element is:
    `<iframe allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen src="/js/ViewerJS/#../Homestake_Lease_Brennan_Agreement.pdf" id="viewerjs_preview"></iframe>`


Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my webserver was not configured to automatically use index.html for "#", and the path that is used in source after locating the ViwerJS directory is meant to be relative to the contents of ViewerJS, not the directory containing ViewerJS.
 The proper format for the iframe is:
`<iframe allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen src="/js/ViewerJS/#index.html../../Homestake_Lease_Brennan_Agreement.pdf" id="viewerjs_preview"></iframe>`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, it's a bit late, but you have to write down this code. In my case I use localhost so it'll be like this:
`<iframe allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen src="http://localhost/js/ViewerJS/#../Homestake_Lease_Brennan_Agreement.pdf" id="viewerjs_preview"></iframe>`

You have to put this code into your html.